# Why does Apple TV always show National Geographic screen saver?

Tags: appletv, screensaver

My 3rd generation Apple TV has a small but annoying problem where it defaults to the National Geographic screen saver, regardless of what is set on the Screen Saver page.

I've chosen > Photos > Explore:

[image]

The next panel shows that I've chosen Flickr (but the situation is identical if I instead choose iCloud photos).

[image]

After the Apple TV has been idle for 2 minutes the screen saver starts. Sometimes it shows 1 image from Flickr then immediately goes into a loop showing the National Geographic photos. Sometimes it shows Flickr photos for ~5 minutes before showing National Geographic.

The OS is set to automatic updates and there are no other issues. It's not exactly a show-stopper bug, just a bit annoying.

(This is the same problem as [Screen saver settings keep defaulting back to National Geographic Photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169732/screen-saver-settings-keep-defaulting-back-to-national-geographic-photos) but applies to Apple TV, not Mac.)

Comment: Grr.. I have the exact same issue!  Have you found a solution yet?  It does appear to have a ticket here, but no resolution:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7026119

Comment: @user952342 nope I never resolved this. It looks like a bug I guess